# Return order of unique values in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, unique

I am trying to find a more efficient way to return the `index` of `unique` values in a `pandas` `df`

For the df below I want to return the index of the first time a unique value occurs.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = ({
    'Day' : ['Mon','Mon','Tues','Mon','Tues','Wed'],                                
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I can manually counti the index of unique value and return below:

```
first = df.iloc[0].Location
second = df.iloc[2].Location 
third = df.iloc[5].Location
```

I was thinking of doing something like

```
first = (df['Day'] == 'Mon')
```

But I still have to change this to find the 2nd, 3rd unique value. Is there a more efficient method?

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want filter all unique index values use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) with `keep=False`:

```
print (df['Day'].drop_duplicates(keep=False))
5    Wed
Name: Day, dtype: object

print (df['Day'].drop_duplicates(keep=False).index)
Int64Index([5], dtype='int64')
```

Or:

```
print (df.index[~df['Day'].duplicated(keep=False)])
Int64Index([5], dtype='int64')
```

If want filter first unique values use only [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print (df['Day'].drop_duplicates())
0     Mon
2    Tues
5     Wed
Name: Day, dtype: object

print (df['Day'].drop_duplicates().index)
Int64Index([0, 2, 5], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you could use:

```
df['Day'].mask(df['Day'].duplicated(keep=False)).dropna().index
```

**Update**

Or update thanks to @Josh Friedlanders suggestion:

```
df[~df['Day'].duplicated(keep=False)].index
```

Comment: Or even simpler, `df[~df.Volume.duplicated(keep=False)].index`